# Python List Comprehension: for and if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi", "mango"]
```

**1**] correct output

**for** is *before* **if**

```
newlist1 = [x for x in fruits if "a" in x]
              ^^^             ^^
```

**2**] **Error** even though **for** is before **if** as in the above statement

```
newlist2 = [x for x in range(10) if x != 5 else 6]
              ^^^                ^^        ^^^^
```

**3**] **correct** output

but here *if* and *else* is *before* **for**

```
newlist3 = [x if x != 5 else 6 for x in range(10)]
              ^^        ^^^^   ^^^
```

May I know why the statement 3 is rendering the output while statement 2 is throwing the error?

Comment: You mixing up the three different used of `if`. 1. correct use as part of the comprehension syntax. 2. statement syntax in a comprehension 3. as ternary operator in a comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example `if x != 5 else 6` is not a filter condition which returns true or false. It's an incomplete statement `<val_1> if <condition> else <val_2>` which does not define <val_1>.
Without 'else' part it's a filter. (example_1)

In the third example your conditional expression is complete `x if x != 5 else 6`.
But it returns value for x and does not filter anything.